# consuming message from activemq queue using spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

So I have application that sends message to activemq queue with spring integration.

```
 <int-feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="feedAdapter"
                                      channel="feedChannel"
                                      auto-startup="${auto.startup:true}"
                                      url="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/49479712">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000"/>
    </int-feed:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="feedChannel"/>

    <int:transformer id="transformer" input-channel="feedChannel"
                     expression="payload.title + payload.author + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}'"
                     output-channel="feedOutputChannel"/>

    <int:channel id="feedOutputChannel"/>

    <jms:outbound-gateway id="jmsOutGateway"
                          request-destination="inputQueue"
                          request-channel="feedOutputChannel"
                          requires-reply="false"/>
```

But now I want to create different application which consumes message from that queue and just prints it out to console with spring integration. I have made this:

```
  <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="JMSInboundAdapter" destination="inputQueue"/>

    <bean id="inputQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="input.queue"/>
    </bean>
```

It works when I run application that sends message to queue. But it doesnt when I run message consume application.
Error I get : `Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.JMSInboundAdapter'.`

How do I need to configure my message consumer application?

Comment: Why do you use `<jms:outbound-gateway`>`? Doesn't look like your consuming application is going to produce some reply... Why doesn't `<jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` work for you?

Comment: I didnt realized that I am kinda very new at this spring integration so I changed it to outbound-channel-adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no `channel` on the adapter, the `id` becomes the channel name.

You need something to subscribe to that channel (e.g. a `<service-activator inputChannel="JMSInboundAdapter" ... />`).

Comment: ```<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="JMSInboundAdapter" destination="inputQueue"/>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="JMSInboundAdapter" ref="demoBean"/>```I added service activator but I get this error now ```no output-channel or replyChannel header available``` is this problem related with my message producer or consumer?

Comment: Your service method needs a return type `void` (or return `null`) to "end" the flow; otherwise, if it returns some value, you need an output channel (and something downstream to consume from it). You can also set `outputChannel="nullChannel"` to discard the service output.